# Stop-and-Wait Protocol - How does it handle last ACK dropped?

Tags: c, network-protocols

I am implementing a client/server echo program using the Stop-and-Wait protocol. Part of the implementation is to randomly introduce drops from the server. I am actually randomly dropping ACKs as well as FRAMEs. A side effect of this is the introduction of a corner case:

If the last ACK from the server is dropped, both client and server end up in a "send" mode. This happens because the server doesn't know the last ACK was dropped, and from its perspective, everything worked and it now should echo back everything the client sent to it.

The client, on the other hand, doesn't know if the last FRAME was dropped or if just the ACK was dropped, so it tries to resend the last FRAME.

I could see this being solved by the use of a FIN or something -- basically an extra ACK going the opposite direction when both sides think transmission is complete. However, I want to conform to the expected approach for Stop-and-Wait.

How should Stop-and-Wait handle this case?

Comment: This should not a problem, the sender gets the timeout on the ACK and resends the frame.  The receiver detects the duplicate frame from the frame number and just discards it.  But still sends the ACK back.  Problem solved.  The Red Flag in the question is "send mode".  Why is there a mode?

Comment: Good point about the `ACK`. However, I'm implementing in UDP, so would it actually get the timeout? Also, the drops are fake, because I'm randomly introducing them and simulating the drop by just not sending the packet (either a `frame` or an `ACK`).

The `send` mode is there because the assignment is to build an echo server. This means I need to create a client and server, built on top of Stop-and-Wait, which operate in two modes: `send` and `receive`. The server is in `receive` mode until it gets an entire file, at which point it switches to `send` mode to echo the entire file back.

Comment: Drop-outs are not fake in UDP, they happen.  Of course you need a timeout, you have to implement it yourself.  A stop-and-wait protocol over UDP isn't exactly competitive with TCP's sliding window.  An echo server lives on the application layer, not the transport layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this situation is to have a one-bit sequence number included in every frame. Every time you send a frame and receive an ACK, you flip the bit for the next frame. If you send a frame, don't receive an ACK, and have to retransmit the frame, you resend it with the same sequence bit.

At the receiver, if you receive two (or more) frames in a row with the same sequence bit, you know it's a retransmission, so you can resend the ACK but ignore the frame, since you've already acted on it.

Don't bother trying to acknowledge acknowledgements. You just run into the same problem where the network might drop the ACK for the ACK.

Comment: I've actually been using 32-bit SEQ #'s for my sanity. My problem fundamentally lies in the fact that I have app-level logic because it's an `echo` program. What this means is that once the server has received the entire file (via S-a-W protocol), it switches modes to `send` and begins transmitting that same file back. Conversely, the client is in the `send` mode to begin with and will try to switch to the `receive` mode after the server has acknowledged all the frames, in anticipation of receiving the echo'd file back. When the last ACK is lost, both server and client end up in `send` mode.

Comment: It seems like I need to my logic inside each of the `receive` and `send` modes so they can switch to the other mode as needed. The difficulty with this is recovering the state they should be in, in terms of what part of the file they are reading/writing

Comment: @ross I think all you need to do at the application layer is to switch modes as soon as you've sent or received the last frame of the file, rather than waiting for acknowledgement that the last frame was received.

Comment: I like that idea. I think i'd need at add a bogus frame at the end though, so it doesn't matter if it's lost

Comment: Doh! The bogus frame is exactly what a `FIN` is. Thanks!

Comment: @ross You don't need the bogus frame. Stop and wait ensures that all frames are eventually delivered, including the last one.